# SQL Server connection through access VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

History of issue. A colleague built an access database and using VBA made a connection to SQL Server. Then running VBA code made a global temp table ##tablename. this information is used in a passthrough query in the database.

I had to build a new database that uses the same logic. I have everything working except that first part. I am missing something in my code and I am not using code correctly to make that SQL Server connection and run my create global table.

I am not too familiar with this part of coding. I am going to need some hand holding here.  I am getting errors no matter what I try.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to reference `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library`.  And yes, paste the relevant code into your question.

Comment: Pictures of code are nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) But for me the bigger concern is using global temp tables. Global temp tables are highly problematic with concurrency. If you have even two people using this code at the same time your temp tables are going to walk all over each other. And then your code pattern is highly problematic as well because you are not parameterizing your queries. [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves this kind of code, you need to fix that.